# Expanded Widget getting Render Error in Flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

I am getting a rendering error when inserting a Expanded widget into the body of a Scafold. I can get around it by using a Container, but would prefer to use Expanded.

I have tried it in a basic scaffold with no other widgets. Here is the error:

https://pastebin.com/uzRveb2r

I only get this error on the web, not on mobile.

Here is code of the page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webenrol/components/enquiries_series.dart';
import 'package:webenrol/constants.dart';
import 'package:webenrol/widgets/enquiries_chart.dart';

class DashboardAdmin extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<EnquiriesSeries> data = [
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'Janurary', enquiries: 50),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'Febuary', enquiries: 75),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'March', enquiries: 80),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'April', enquiries: 100),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'May', enquiries: 120),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'June', enquiries: 150),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'July', enquiries: 10),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'August', enquiries: 50),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'September', enquiries: 70),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'October', enquiries: 50),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'November', enquiries: 130),
    EnquiriesSeries(month: 'December', enquiries: 450),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Total Number of Enquiries from X centres',
                          style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '546',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Website Enquiries', style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '10',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Phone Enquiries', style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '15',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Walk-in Enquiries', style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '6',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Email Enquiries', style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '15',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Other Enquiries', style: kDashboardCardTitle),
                      Text(
                        '115',
                        style: kDashboardLargeNumber,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Card(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('History of Enquiries'),
                      Expanded(child: Text('Hello World!')),
//                      EnquiriesChart(
//                        data: data,
//                      ),
                    ],
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe because your expanded widget located in a column  where the column itself is a children of another column.

the column that you create doesnot have defined height itself, and maybe it lead to an error because it doesnot know the expand height.

Wrap with SizedBox or Container with defined height will work.

try out this code in https://dartpad.dev/

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Store Warehouse',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DashboardAdmin(),
        ),
    );
  }
}


class DashboardAdmin extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
//           Row(
//             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
//             children: <Widget>[
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Total Number of Enquiries from X centres',
//                          ),
//                       Text(
//                         '546',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Website Enquiries',),
//                       Text(
//                         '10',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Phone Enquiries',),
//                       Text(
//                         '15',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Walk-in Enquiries', ),
//                       Text(
//                         '6',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Email Enquiries',),
//                       Text(
//                         '15',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//               Card(
//                 child: Padding(
//                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
//                   child: Column(
//                     children: <Widget>[
//                       Text('Other Enquiries',),
//                       Text(
//                         '115',
//                       )
//                     ],
//                   ),
//                 ),
//               ),
//             ],
//           ),
          Container(height: 200, child:
          Card(

              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('History of Enquiries'),
                      Text('History of Enquiries'),

                      Expanded(child: Text('Hello World!')),
                    ],
                  ))),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was hoping not to fix a height, and for the card to expand to the height it required. If I rebuild this page, how would I lay it out for that to happen?

Comment: if you want the height to match the entire left space, just replace the Container into Expanded and remove the height. But maybe it will lead to another possibility error, maybe